# Diferente evento onclick para cada parte de un recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-studio, recyclerview, android-recyclerview

Tengo una app con un recyclerview el cual le tengo implementado `View.OnClickListener` en su respectivo adapter, toda la funcionalidad de OnClick funciona perfectamente para cada item del recyclerview el problema es que quiero que se comporte diferente dependiendo de en que parte del item fue "clickeado"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para poner un ejemplo con esta imagen quiero que si el usuario clickea la sección (1) del item ocurra un evento en particular en vez de que dicho evento ocurra si el item fue clickeado en cualquier otra parte del mismo.

en conclusión si el usuario clickea la seccion (1) del item, que la app haga el `Evento1` y así sucesivamente con todas las secciones del item del recyclerview

Comment: Muestra el código java del activity/fragmen y del adapater y el xml del item row y así saber que es la seccion 1,2 y 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no tengo claro si esto es lo que necesitas.

Cuando le quieras dar a una sección dentro de una fila en el recyclerView debes colocar un setOnClickListener por cada sección en la que quieres que haga algo diferente, esto lo debes hacer en tu adaptador.

En el ejemplo de abajo tienes dos botones (ITEM1 y ITEM2), para que cada uno realice una acción diferente debes implementar el OnClickListener dentro del método `onBinViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position)`.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {


public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


    public Button ITEM1;
    public Button ITEM1;

    public MyViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        ITEM1 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.idITEM1);
        ITEM2 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.idITEM2);
    }
}



@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.ITEM1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Aquí va todo lo que necesites que haga cuando le des click en el ítem 1
        }
    });

    holder.ITEM2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Aquí va todo lo que necesites que haga cuando le des click en el ítem 2
        }
    });
}}
```